# UISearchBar iOS 8 clarification

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios8, uisearchbar

I'm trying to get special behavior of `UISearchBar`. I want never to show "Cancel" button (this part i'm already implement) and show Bookmarks button always.

But if i hide cancel button, bookmarks button is hide too in editing mode (only if `searchBar.text.length > 0`)

How i hide cancel button:

```
UITextField *textField = [searchBar valueForKey:@"_searchField"];
textField.clearButtonMode = UITextFieldViewModeNever;
```

Picks:

[image]

[image]

My question is how can i always show only bookmarks button?

Answer (score 0):

You also need to set this:

textField.rightViewMode = UITextFieldViewModeAlways;